# custom provider won't run msiexec

Tags: puppet

I created a type and provider to check if a program is installed, and run msiexec if it isn't. My output at running the agent shows the program as 'ensure=absent', but it doesn't start the msi install. Can anyone see what's wrong with my code?

Event viewer doesn't show the msi install running

My custom type:

```
Puppet::Type.newtype(:custom) do
  @doc = "Custom type"
  ensurable

  newparam(:name) do
    desc "name of program."
  end

  newparam(:source) do
    desc "The full path to the file."
  end
end
```

my provider:

```
Puppet::Type.type(:custom).provide(:win) do
  desc "."

  def create
    exec "msiexec.exe /i " + @resource[:source] + " /quiet"
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def exists?
    begin
      exec "puppet resource package " + @resource[:name]
    rescue Puppet::ExecutionFailure => e
      false
    end
  end
end
```

my manifest

```
class mod {    
  custom { 'AppNameHere':
    ensure => present,
    source => 'Q:\\app.msi',
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the relevant agent debug output for this resource?

Answer (score 0):

With Puppet on Windows, there is no shell. You need to provide full paths (absolute paths) to everything.